# Homestead on Windows 10 unreachable via 192.168.10.10

Tags: vagrant, homestead

I have Homestead up and running with the code folder mapped to a folder on my drives and showing the content fine. I have a laravel project in it and have mapped homestead.test to /home/vagrant/code/projectname/public. I checked that the path to the directory is right and have tried re-provisioning and destroying the box, but 192.168.10.10 is still unreachable. I cannot ping it from the host machine or when ssh'd into the Homestead box. I have restarted the host machine as well.

Does anyone have any suggestions of things to check?

Comment: Have you defined a private network for the machine in its Vagranfile? I don't have a homestead machine running, but my other machine has ```config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"``` in its Vagrantfile, in the ```Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|``` block. Homestead wraps this up in its ```Homestead.yaml``` file like documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead#network-interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with not having the most up to date version of Virtualbox installed. For anyone else with this issue, I would check that Vagrant, Virtualbox and the Homestead box are all on the most up to date versions.